# Error when using the train function when using SVM for classification

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I am new to machine learning and R as a whole and I am trying to use the built-in caret function to train a classification SVM to predict wether a stock price will move up or down. You can find my code below:

```
library(caret)
library(kernlab)

# Load Data Here

sample_size = floor(0.85*nrow(DataSet))

trainSet = DataSet[1:sample_size,1:(ncol(DataSet)-1)]
testSet = DataSet[(sample_size+1):nrow(DataSet),1:(ncol(DataSet)-1)]

survived = DataSet[1:sample_size,ncol(DataSet),with = FALSE]
survivedtest = DataSet[(sample_size+1):nrow(DataSet),ncol(DataSet),with = FALSE]
survived = as.factor(survived$AAPL.res)
survivedtest = as.factor(survivedtest$AAPL.res)
setattr(survived,"levels",c("UP", "DOWN"))
setattr(survivedtest,"levels",c("UP", "DOWN"))

ctrl = trainControl(method = "LGOCV",
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     index = list(TrainSet = 1:nrow(trainSet)),
                     savePredictions = TRUE,
                     verboseIter =TRUE)

set.seed(201)
sigmaRangeFull = sigest(as.matrix(trainSet))
svmRGridFull = expand.grid(sigma =  as.vector(sigmaRangeFull)[1],C = 2^(-3:4))

set.seed(476)
svmRFit = train(x = trainSet, 
                 y = survived,
                 method = "svmRadial",
                 metric = "ROC",
                 preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                 tuneGrid = svmRGridFull,
                 trControl = ctrl)
svmRFit
```

When I try to train the model I reach the error:

```
> svmRFit = train(x = trainSet, 
+                  y = survived,
+                  method = "svmRadial",
+                  metric = "ROC",
+                  preProc = c("center", "scale"),
+                  tuneGrid = svmRGridFull,
+                  trControl = ctrl)
+ TrainSet: sigma=0.001371, C= 0.125 
+ TrainSet: sigma=0.001371, C= 0.250 
+ TrainSet: sigma=0.001371, C= 0.500 
+ TrainSet: sigma=0.001371, C= 1.000 
+ TrainSet: sigma=0.001371, C= 2.000 
+ TrainSet: sigma=0.001371, C= 4.000 
+ TrainSet: sigma=0.001371, C= 8.000 
+ TrainSet: sigma=0.001371, C=16.000 
Error in { : task 1 failed - "replacement has 1 row, data has 0"
In addition: There were 48 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

I am unsure as to what exactly is causing the issue since the Data is made of numeric values and the y outcome is a factor. I have also tried with other forms of train control methods and reached the same issue. The data used can be found here: [Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j6gy0sfxr5sps1s/ModelData.Rdata?dl=0)

P.S. Any comments on how to improve the code\coding practises are very welcome, since I am trying to learn.

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129561/r-caret-package-rfe-never-finishes-error-task-1-failed-replacement-has-length, might give you an idea where you making the mistake!

Comment: When running your code, I get an error when creating the `survived` object: `Error in [.data.frame(DataSet, 1:sample_size, ncol(DataSet), with = FALSE) :  unused argument (with = FALSE)`